# Using values from one field as parameters and another field to label in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I have this attribute table from a shapefile of a road network. I want to labels to display "ROAD_NAME" but I want them to appear at different scales. I would like to use "Length_Cat" to group which roads appear at which scale.

is there a way I can use an SQL expression?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a huge range of values in Length_Cat, you can do this by changing your label Method (first drop-down in Labels tab) to **Define classes for features and label each class differently**.

[image]

Add the number of classes you want (to match the values in your Length_Cat) and then set a SQL Query for each one to match the values in Length_Cat.

[image]

Then for each Class, set a different scale as per your requirements.

[image]